# How to define $(this) correctly in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I apply `each` method,I confused to define `this`.

When I click element , I would like to get each cells `id` but it seems that `this` show entire `calendar`

my question is

① Why `this` show `#calendar` when I click cells ?

② How to  define and get each `id` when I click cells?

If someone has experienced same problem, please let me know.

Thanks

```js
var $ = jQuery;
const $days = $(this).find('.day');

function register() {
  function clicked() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('is-clicked');
    
    let clickedID=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log("clickedID",clickedID);
  }

  $(this).on({
    click: clicked
  });
}
$("#calendar").each(register);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.is-clicked {
  background-color: aqua;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id=1 class=day>1</td>
      <td id=2 class=day>2</td>
      <td id=3 class=day>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sre spplying `each` on the `#calendar` and it wil apply handler to that so `this` would refers to it always.

Instead you need to apply `each` on `.day` to iterate over cells and binding handler.

```
$("#calendar .day").each(register);
```

```js
function register() {
  function clicked() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('is-clicked');

    let clickedID = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("clickedID", clickedID);
  }

  $(this).on({
    click: clicked
  });
}
$("#calendar .day").each(register);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.is-clicked {
  background-color: aqua;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id=1 class=day>1</td>
      <td id=2 class=day>2</td>
      <td id=3 class=day>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring to the calender. Remove `this` and add `td`.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
const $days = $(this).find('.day');

function register() {
  function clicked() {
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('is-clicked');
    
    let clickedID=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log("clickedID",clickedID);
  }
  console.log(this) 
  $('td').on({  //===========> Add td instead of this
    click: clicked
  });
}
$("#calendar").each(register);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.is-clicked {
  background-color: aqua;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id=1 class=day>1</td>
      <td id=2 class=day>2</td>
      <td id=3 class=day>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```